# How to make HTML5 audio api run in background in Cordova Angular project for IOS?

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, html5-audio

I have a Cordova Angular project, which plays audio using HTML5 Audio API. After adding the WKWebview plugin to the project the app stops playing in the background in IOS.

Also, set the WKSuspendInBackground value false in config.xml.

This is my config.xml.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.syncyourfocus" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>SyncYourFocus</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="WKSuspendInBackground" value="false" />
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

           </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
        <preference name="WKSuspendInBackground" value="false" />
     
       </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please add config.xml and code relevant to playback

Comment: @ihorbond I have added the config.xml file.